# Is it possible to move image files from a text thread on a phone to a virtual box without downloading them?

Tags: android, sandbox, image, bot

I'm looking into a spam bot that's been sending me messages on my phone (Samsung s10). It's sent a couple images that I want to try and scrape for metadata and do a reverse image search on. Since the images are from an untrusted source I don't want to download them to my phone. Is there a way to safely get these images into a virtual box?

Comment: What is the current state of the images on your phone? Like, if they were received as MMS, the phone almost certainly already downloaded them; this is optional behavior but on by default in almost all messaging apps. Saving the image into your Pictures folder isn't any more "downloading it" than fetching it for inline display (and storage) in the messaging app.

Comment: @CBHacking Yes, they were received as MMS and are displayed inline. I guess that kind of defeats the point of my question. For future reference, if they had not been auto displayed would there still be a way to get them off the phone and into a vm?

Comment: Yes, image messages are actually a weird SMS with a URL inside them. If you can get the URL - usually possible via things like SMS backup tools, or a custom app set to handle SMS, or possibly just by using an intercepting proxy on the phone's connection - you can instead download that URL to another device. You might have to do it through the phone's connection, or otherwise authenticate as being the phone, for the server to let you request the image though (and note that MMS sometimes uses a different data gateway than normal or tethered phone data).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the particular SMS application, version of Android, and what privileges you have.

Some apps might simply place files in a folder on the SD card,  readable by anyone. Others may use some kind of private data or cache location that is only accessible to the particular app.  In this case, you'd likely need root access to read these files.